# perpetual music geo machine

Tags: geology, music, geophysics

while traveling the world merchants have noticed the sound of many melodies repeating through night and days, in some regions melodies shift tone or speed based on the time of the day, and each region has different sounds.

later it was found that the music originated from mechanical perpetual instruments which harnessed the various energies of the earth ; waves, wind and heat to activate gears and levers, beads, buttons and spikes producing sequences of sounds that mammals can recognize as melodies.

Given the materials available in the average planet, how long could those mechanisms last before the wind, heat and waves corrode them to the point of them not producing any meaningful music.

Comment: Do you consider wind chimes to be music?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suikinkutsu.**

https://traditionalkyoto.com/gardens/suikinkutsu/

[image: suikinkutsu]

> When you visit some of Kyoto’s gardens, you may hear the beautiful
> sound of water drops emanates from the scenery itself. In traditional
> gardens at temples and parks throughout Japan, this is the sound of
> “suikinkutsu” – literally “water koto cave”. Not unlike glass or metal
> wind chimes which tinkle in the breeze, the pleasant echo of water
> drops from a suikinkutsu conjures a calm, cooling sensation rooted in
> Japanese culture. The zither-like sound recalls the traditional
> instrument of the koto, hence its name. Also functioning as a drainage
> device, the suikinkutsu has been called a masterpiece of landscape
> architecture.

The link has videos where you can listen.  It is very nice.  There are not gears and levers; the moving part is water alone but that is what gives it its elegance and also durabilty.  As regards how long it could last - how long could a carved stone or ceramic pot with clear water dripping into it last underground?  A few thousand years I suspect.  The oldest ones in Japan are only a few hundred years.